# how do i redirect a specific path to another path in nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I need to redirect a specific path:

```
mydomain.com/old-path/
```

to a new path, permanently:

```
mydomain.com/new-path/
```

i am using elgg software (elgg.org) and presently when someone navigates to the /old-path/ folder they view a page (rather than a folder listing) - thus no specific page name is used.

i tried the various methods of redirecting that can be found via google for nginx and so far none have had any effect. they mostly are either for a specific page or a directory, yet what i am doing, is, i suppose, technically neither a specific page or a directory..

anyone know how to achieve this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) to do this.

```
rewrite ^/old-directory/(.*)$ /new-directory/$1 last;
```

Comment: thanks for responding.. that did not have any effect either.
i would say that maybe i don't have rewrites enabled. but i do because there are many others active in the config already (that i did not write myself) for other purposes.

Comment: That's really odd. :( I actually use this exact rule myself because my site used to be at `www.domain.com/public/` and it's now at `www.domain.com/`.

Comment: perhaps the issue is the formatting of the paths i am using.. both begin and end with slashes.. other than that, i am out of ideas

Comment: Rewriting like thus does not change the URL. Do you expect the URL to change?

Comment: i'd prefer the URL to change in this instance, though that is not a requirement. presently no change is occurring, the 'old' page is being rendered